# Data mapping platform

Tags: api, gis, mapping, research

Is here.com a good platform for mapping/tracking scientific species information for a bio study? (I started with google maps, but the library went obsolete and they're now asking for billing info to refresh an API key.)

Will we lose ownership of our data if we store it in Here's XYZ cloud space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use open data sources (like [openstreetmap](http://openstreetmap.org/)), which you can control and work with as you like. 
The license models are much more friendly for publications and scientific work in general.

For an API which you can control with simple python scripts look at http://geopandas.org/

You will find many good links from there.

Will you loose ownership on your data, if you store it on a computer you do not have under control?

Imagine you give a memory stick with the only copy of your thesis to a stranger and ask him to hand it out once a day at a meeting point so that you can work.

Comment: GeoPandas is for Python (and is excellent). For browser based JS, use Leaflet

Comment: @Mawg Thank you, I have added the hint about Python to my answer.